# Google Search Appliance querying date meta field with given range

Tags: date-range, google-search-appliance

I want to send a query to the Google Search Appliance that includes date range criteria of a meta field (lets call it metaDate). For example: metaDate field between 01.01.2010 and 01.01.2015. How can i construct a query such like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mohan's not entirely correct.  You can perform range searches on any metadata attribute.  This is different then the document date.  See [Google's Documentation](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/admin_console_help/serve_dynamic_navigation.html) for this.

Also you can create a dynamic navigation element and test the format yourself.  Dynamic Navigation can be used to construct range searches.

Comment: After creating a dynamic navigation, how can i fire a query with a desired date range? inmeta parameter?

Comment: That worked! dynamic navigation search gives the desired range search statement. All you need to do is define dynamic navigation with meta parameters that stores date will be fired a range search, and then acquire the dynamic navigation script to give a search results with pre-defined meta range options. That process gives you a query like this: q=event+inmeta:end%252Ddate:2010-02-01..2010-02-28+inmeta:start%252Ddate:2010-01-01..2010-03-31

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell GSA to use metaDate as Lastmodifieddate either by adding it as Last-Modified response header or by configuring Document Dates in GSA admin console for metaDate. After the changes, reindex your documents and fire a date range query along with the query term. 
For example, q=someterm daterange:2010-01-01..2015-01-01

Comment: Thanks, i've configured my meta fields in Document Dates. I got 2 meta fields that store date values. The one is "start-date", and the other one is "end-date". How can i use these two date fields to fire a range query?

Comment: I have no clue how you can perform daterange query operation with two date metafields. But I can suggest something. I have implemented similar requirement in the past. What I did was, requested content team to introduce a flag called "active" and asked them to update with yes (active=yes) if the document's end date is greater than current date. Also, we kept one metafield to kept track of document last modified date. And we used last modified date and flag to filter out results.